# Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException: Incorrect declared batch size, records still remaining in file

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We meet the problem when consume message from kafka-2.2.1 and We config `compression.type = zstd` on the kafka broker.The full exception stack is

```java
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Received exception when fetching the next record from test-10. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1519)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1374)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:676)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:631)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1282)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1240)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1168)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaConsumerThread.run(KafkaConsumerThread.java:258)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException: Incorrect declared batch size, records still remaining in file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the problem at last. We check the jar version used is kafka conumser and we found the version of `zstd-jni-1.3.2-2.jar` was lower than the kafka broker which is `zstd-jni-1.3.8-1.jar`. The jar version was conflict in `pom.xml`, because we depend on spark-core in the pom.xml and this jar indirect depend on `zstd-jni-1.3.2-2.jar`. So just exclude zstd from spark-core solved this.So check the version of compress and uncompress jar used in both broker and client. (e.g., zstd,lz4,snappy,gzip)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>${spark.scope}</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>zstd-jni</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.github.luben</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```